# Equivalent for Dancer of Mojolicious Mojolicious::Plugin::PODRenderer?

Tags: perl, documentation-generation, mojolicious, dancer, perl-pod

I would like to generate documentation in a `Dancer` application in the same way that `Mojolicious` does with [`Mojolicious::Plugin::PODRenderer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aPODRenderer), I mean in the browser, under the `/perldoc` path.

Does somebody knows a module that can help? I found no ready-made plugin for `Dancer`. If it don't exist, any recommandation is welcome.

Comment: As a developer of Mojolcious, may I ask, is there some external reason why you are not developing a Mojolicious application? If Dancer is for you then great, but if you had some difficulty with Mojo and moved on, I would be happy to help.

Comment: I appreciate your proposal for help Joel. I am currently testing both Frameworks. I'm searching for the one that will have the most documentation and simple examples for common things understandable by an intermediate-beginner. I am not interesting by extreme performance facts. I have read about the Dancer-likes-CPAN VS Mojo-has-no-dependencies debate, and admit it don't really helps to choose. Both are dead simple to start with (dependencies or not), but the fact you answer first could help me to choose. The PODRenderer plugin is very interesting and maybe I would like to hack a bit with it.

Comment: We like to think we have very good documentation. To address some common questions, first read the doc for [Mojolicious::Lite](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite) (which is the tutorial and should not be skipped) then read the guides in the order seen [here](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc). Also, individual class docs are reference and not intended as tutorial.

Comment: This is a precious thing to have a path to follow into the guides an tutorials and not skipping the *::lite* part.

Comment: Many people skip the `::Lite` tutorial, because they are only interested in a full app. However many important concepts are introduced and the lite syntax is used throughout the documentation. It really shouldn't be skipped. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porting Mojolicious' PODRenderer to Dancer should be fairly simple - it's an example plugin and the code is fairly short. I've done this for my own use in my CGI framework at work.

https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/PODRenderer.pm#L34

Essentially what the plugin does is define the route `/perldoc/:module` to call the `_perldoc` method; the `_perldoc` method uses `Pod::Simple::Search` to find a documentation file matching the module param in the `@INC` directories; If it doesn't, it redirects the search to MetaCPAN. If it does, it uses `Pod::Simple::HTML` to convert the documentation to HTML, which is then tidied up with `Mojo::DOM` and wrapped in a lovely template.

Finding the location of that template is left as an exercise for... oh, nevermind, here it is: https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/templates/perldoc.html.ep

Comment: That last link is now 404. New location (pinned at the current latest release v7.03): https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/v7.03/lib/Mojolicious/resources/templates/mojo/perldoc.html.ep